# MapView Not Centering on User's Location Despite Availability in iOS using Mapbox

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm working on an iOS app using mapboc where I need to center a map view on the user's current location. I've written a function, recenterMap, that is supposed to check if the user's location is available and then update the map's camera to center on this location. However, the map doesn't seem to recenter even though the user's location is available.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
@objc func recenterMap() {
// Check if the user's location is available
if let userLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
    // Create camera options to center the map on the user's location
    let cameraOptions = CameraOptions(center: userLocation, zoom: 15)

    // Update the map's camera
    navigationMapView.mapView.camera.ease(to: cameraOptions, duration: 1.0)

    print("User location is available.")
} else {
    print("User location is not available.")
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I see the "User location is available." print statement in the console, indicating that the if condition is met and the location is indeed available. However, the map view doesn't update to center on the user's location as expected.

I've checked the following:

- Location services are enabled.
- The app has the necessary permissions to access location data.
- The locationManager is properly configured and working (since it's
  providing the current location).

What could be causing the map not to recenter on the user's location even though the location data is available and the camera update code is being executed? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!